# Building RPM issue

Tags: rpm, centos6, rpmbuild

I tried to build RPM while following this guide http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=3307

but, when I have reached this step, when I want to copy the **CentOS-tup.repo**

> cd ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES
>
> mkdir -p tuprepo-1/etc/yum.repos.d
>
> cp /tmp/CentOS-Tup.repo !$

I keep getting an error that **/Tpm/CentOS-Tup.repo directory not found.**

So where can I find the CentOS-tup.repo ?
or is there a repo that I need to install?

Comment: It seems CentOS-Tup.repo is an unspecified yum repositiry file, which the blog post does not teach you how to write.

Comment: oh okay. So how to write the file ? or is there a package containing the said file that needs to be installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://tecadmin.net/create-rpm-of-your-own-script-in-centosredhat/) shows a full explanation on how to build RPM by yourself.